# Echoing from UART in Keil w/ 2104

Tags: assembly, arm, uart, keil, microprocessors

Question: I am using ARM assembly language to program the LPC2104 microprocessor and I'm simply trying to make a program that receives input from the UART and transmits it back. It worked just fine with just transmitting a string from memory, but I modified it by adding a receive subroutine and taking away the string in memory. The issue must be with the receive subroutine, because I can't even type into the UART1. I have yet to edit the contents of "loop" properly, so just disregard that for now. This is my first semester working in ARM assembly or with microprocessors, so please explain as you would to a layman.

Here is my code:

```
        AREA uartdemo, CODE, READONLY
pinsel0    EQU  0xE002C000; controls function of pins
u0start    EQU  0xE000C000; start of UART0 registers
lcr0       EQU  0xC;        line control register for UART0
lsr0       EQU  0x14;       line status register for UART0
ramstart   EQU  0x40000000; start of onboard RAM for 2104
stackstart EQU  0x40000200; start of stack

ENTRY

start
    LDR sp, =stackstart; set up stack pointer
    BL  UARTConfig;      initialize/configure UART0
loop
    BLNE Receive;        receive character from UART
    BLNE Transmit;       send character to UART
    BNE  loop;           continue if not a '0'
done B done;             otherwise, we are done             

; subroutine UARTConfig
;   Configures the I/O pins first.
;   Then sets up the UART control register.
;   Parameters set to 8 bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit.
;   Registers used:
;   r5 - scratch register
;   r6 - scratch register
;   inputs:  none
;   outputs:  none
UARTConfig
    PUSH {r5, r6, lr};
    LDR  r5, =pinsel0;    base address of register
    LDR  r6, [r5];        get contents
    BIC  r6, r6, #0xf;    clear out lower nibble
    ORR  r6, r6, #0x5;    sets P0.0 to Tx0 and P0.1 to Rx0
    STR  r6, [r5];        r/modify/w back to register
    LDR  r5, =u0start;
    MOV  r6, #0x83;       set 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
    STRB r6, [r5, #lcr0]; write control byte to LCR
    MOV  r6, #0x61;       9600 baud @ 15MHz VPB clock
    STRB r6, [r5];        store control byte
    MOV  r6, #3;          set DLAB = 0
    STRB r6, [r5, #lcr0]; Tx and Rx buffers set up
    POP  {r5, r6, pc};

; subroutine Transmit
;   Puts one byte into the UART for transmitting
;   Registers used:
;   r5 - scratch register
;   r6 - scratch register
;   inputs:  r0 - byte to transmit
;   outputs:  none
Transmit
     PUSH {r5, r6, lr};
     LDR  r5, =u0start;
wait LDRB r6, [r5, #lsr0];  get status of buffer
     TST  r6, #0x20;        buffer empty?
     BEQ wait;              spin until buffer is empty
     STRB r0, [r5];
     POP {r5, r6, pc};

; subroutine Receive
;   Takes one byte from the UART for transmitting
;   Registers used:
;   r5 - scratch register
;   r6 - scratch register
;   inputs:  r0 - byte to transmit X
;   outputs:  none                 X
Receive
     PUSH {r5, r6, lr};
     LDR  r5, =u0start;
wait2 LDRB r6, [r5, #lsr0];  get status of buffer
     TST  r6, #0x00;        buffer empty?
     BEQ wait2;              spin until buffer is empty
     STRB r0, [r5];
     POP {r5, r6, pc};

    END
```

Comment: Single-step through with the debugger, paying close attention to the CPU registers; predict how you expect each instruction to change the system state, then step it to compare what really happens. At some point the observed and expected behaviours won't match, and that's your bug. Have a think about why `tst r6, #0` isn't a particularly useful thing to do, and probably isn't doing what you think it is. Then in spite of that consider why your "receive" routine fundamentally can't receive anything anyway.

Comment: I think I need to wait for the buffer to be full or use the DR status bit, but I'm not sure how to

Comment: Waiting for it to be full is a bad idea, you only need it to be not empty. And you aren't going to find out what's making it not empty by _writing_ to the data register...